# Trying to understand count(*) in neo4j query

Tags: neo4j

The standard movie DB in neo4j has a standard query:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors),
  (coActors)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(cocoActors)
WHERE NOT (tom)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(cocoActors) AND tom <> cocoActors
RETURN cocoActors.name AS Recommended, count(*) AS Strength ORDER BY Strength DESC
```

This query should return the name of actors who have played as coActors in movies with actors who have been coActors of Tom Hanks, and it will exclude from the cocoActors Tom Hanks himself and any coActors.

I am trying to understand what "Strength" is. I though it was the number of movies where the cocoActor has played with a coActor of Tom Hanks.

If I modify the query to be:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors),
  (coActors)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(cocoActors)
WHERE NOT (tom)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(cocoActors) AND tom <> cocoActors
RETURN coActors.name, cocoActors.name AS Recommended, count(*) AS Strength ORDER BY Strength DESC
```

I get a totally different result. What is the strength here? Why are the two queries returning different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different `Strength` value is due to the addition of an extra [grouping key](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#grouping-keys) (`coActors.name`) to influence the aggregating function `COUNT`.

As [documented](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#_introduction):

> Aggregating functions take a set of values and calculate an aggregated
> value over them. Aggregation can be computed over all the matching
> paths, or it can be further divided by introducing grouping keys.
> Grouping keys are non-aggregating expressions that are used to group
> the values going into the aggregating functions.

In your second query, `coActors.name` and `cocoActors.name` are "non-aggregating expressions", so the `RETURN` clause specifies that `Strength` should be the number of times each unique pair of coActor and cocoActor acted together (in a movie in which Tom Hanks did not act, in your use case). This can cause the same `Recommended` cocoActor to appear multiple times in the result, each time with a different coActor.

In your first query, the only "non-aggregating expression" was `cocoActors.name`, so the `RETURN` clause specifies that `Strength` should be the number of times the `Recommended` cocoActor acted together with a coActor of Tom Hank's in a movie in which Tom Hanks did not act.

Comment: Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Thank you. I created new queries to see what is going on:
MATCH (p1:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]-(m1:Movie)-[:ACTED_IN]-(p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]-(m2:Movie)-[:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person {name:"Tom Cruise"})
RETURN p1, m1, m2, p2, p
In the second query, you're correct that strength is the number of times each unique pair of coActor and cocoActor acted together.
In the first, it seems that it's the number of paths, from Tom Hanks to the cocoActor. So, it's actually the opposite, it's the total number of times Tom Hanks acted together with a any coActor who acted as coActor of the cocoActor.

Comment: For example, between Tom Hanks and Tom Cruise I get 5. Tom Hanks acted 3 times with Meg Ryan, 1 with Kevin Bacon, 1 with Bonnie Hunt. Tom Cruise acted once with each of them.

Comment: Or actually is the maximum number of possible paths from Tom Hanks to the cocoActor

Comment: If you want to look at it that way, but the phrase "possible paths from Tom Hanks to the cocoActor" can be confusing, since in reality Tom Hanks never acted with the cocoActor.

Comment: If you run the query I wrote it makes sense. You start from Tom Hanks, go to a movie, to the coActor, another movie and then the cocoActor. If you count all the possible paths, that is what count(*) is. Maybe you see it in a different way, to me it seems that is the most intuitive way to understand it. I will probably expand this in an answer later, in case some other people find it useful, but I will select yours as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Strength" is just an aggregated value. '*' represents the number of rows e.g. count rows.

The original field "cocoActors.name AS Recommended" is the grouping variable, so if you had:

```
Recommended 
___________

Joe Bloggs
Joe Bloggs
```

it becomes:

```
Recommended | Strength 
______________________
Joe Bloggs  |     2
```

So you are counting the number of times any given combination of coActors.name & cocoActors.name appears in the match results.